# How can i edit this navigation bar? MAGENTO

Tags: magento, menu, navigation

So i am new to magento and web development and i am in the middle of putting together my own site which is here [theshirt.org](http://www.theshirt.org) i am trying to change the look of this vertical navigation menu which i made following the instructions on this wiki

[Creating a vertical navigation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/how_to_create_a_vertical_left_hand_menu)

I am trying to change a few things on this navigation but i just have no clue where to start.

1. As i have changed the size of my main and left sidebar, the nav menu is too big so will i will need to change the size of the nav menu to 150px
2. the nav menu only appears on the home page. I need it to appear of every page
3. When i hover over the navigation categories i would like the menu items to change colour.

now how would i go about doing this?

Thanks again guys for your help. I would not have been able todo any of my store without the help of this site!

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1°) Look at http://theshirt.org/skin/frontend/default/footprint/css/widgets.css and edit width:200px to width:130px around line 155

```
#nav_vert li {
background-color: #F6F6F6;
border-bottom: thin solid #CCCCCC;
list-style: none outside none;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
width: 130px;
}
```

2°) You must have missed the first step of your tutorial :

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

move this in the `<default>` section
it will show the menu in all page with a left column.

3°) Just do some CSS here to look at the :hover pseudo-element

Basically in the same css than for 1°) (widget.css) look at line 202 and replace #nav_vert a:hover by #nav_vert span:hover to have your text grey on mouse over. Then you can play with color, or background-color or whatever you want ;)

Edit.:
To transform a page to a 2 columns with left bar, edit your xml layout files to change the template of the `<reference name="head">` on page you want.

For CMS page you can set this directly through a menu when creating the page.

Comment: i am having trouble displaying the navigation on all pages :( I moved the code shown above to the default section in layout/catalog.xml

Comment: i have just "inspected element" on my website using google chrome and i cant see the div class "col-left sidebar". I can see the div for the right side. is this the cause?

Comment: If the page is displayed with 1 column or 2 columns with right bar it won't work. 
For right bar you need `<reference name="right">` instead of "left"

Comment: well i want all my pages to be 2 columns with left sidebar and i want the vertical navigation to be on every single page i make. even if its a contact us page

Comment: do you have an email address? i have tried to contact you via your website but the contact button doesnt work yet. i would like a quote? you can email me jonwhittle89@gmail.com